# Spring data CrudRepository exists

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When I extend `CrudRepository` interface, I have `exists(ID)` method in my subinteface. I can write `findBy<property>` methods.

Is it possible somehow to write `existBy<property>` method that will return `boolean`. Or to annotate it with `@Query(jpa query)` so it will return `boolean`.

I know that I can do `select count(*)` and return `long`, but then I will have to do `!=0` check in my service layer.

Comment: "but then I will have to do !=0 check in my service layer." Also using exist instead of count would be slightly more efficient for db query

Answer (score 25):

@Oleksandr's answer is correct, but the only way I could get it to work is as follows.  I'm using Eclipselink on PostgreSQL.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(u) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM User u WHERE u.username = ?1")
    public Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: It's a good workaround for Spring Data before v1.11.0. @alexander-camperov please accept this answer if you agree that it solves your problem.

Answer (score 23):

As of Spring Data JPA `1.11.0.RELEASE`, you can now use `exists` with query derivation from method names. For example, if you have a `User` entity with an `email` property, you can do this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: It seems `existsBy` is broken by now :C https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-851

Comment: It works and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 21):

Actually you can use case expression like this:

```
select case when count(e) > 0 then true else false end from Entity e
where e.property = ?1 -- here go your conditions
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source for `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.exists(ID)` then you will see that it uses a `TypedQuery` to count records and returns:

```
query.getSingleResult() == 1
```

You can create a query that does something similar for your `existsBy(...)` methods.

Comment: yeah, I looked in the source code. By then I'll have to implement my Dao interface. I was looking for solution when I wont have to do that =)